# How to call the post method in notification project from web api project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, constructor

Here is my code , there are 2 projects web api project and notification project,
How to access post method of notification project from web api project.

```
namespace NotificationApi.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class MessageController : Controller
    {
        private IHubContext<NotifyHub, ITypedHubClient> _hubContext;

        public MessageController (IHubContext<NotifyHub, ITypedHubClient> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            MessageVM messageVM = new MessageVM();
            messageVM.Payload = "hii";
            messageVM.Type = "success";
              this.Post(messageVM);
    }


        [HttpPost]
        [DisableCors]
        public string Post([FromBody]MessageVM msg)
        {
            string retMessage = string.Empty;
            try
            {

        _hubContext.Clients.All.BroadcastMessage(msg.Type, msg.Payload);
                retMessage = "Success";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                retMessage = e.ToString();
            }
            return retMessage;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you paste the controller of the web api project where you want to call from

Answer (score 0):

For accessing method between two web api projecct, you could try `HttpClient` to send request.

- `MessageVM`

  ```
      public class MessageVM
  {
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Method from web api

  ```
  [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class HttpClientController : ControllerBase
  {
      private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
      public HttpClientController(HttpClient httpClient)
      {
          _httpClient = httpClient;
      }

      public async Task CallWebApi()
      {
          string url = @"https://localhost:44342/api/message/post";
          var model = new MessageVM {
              Id = 1,
              Name = "Test"
          };
          var response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, model);
          var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: @Ruchikaperera Glad to hear it works, would you mind accepting this solution as answer?

Comment: how to do that ?